# Multiple Frameworks for Risk Assessments?

Tags: risk-management, risk, nist

My organization utilizes Risk Assessments as the catalyst for a lot of our Information Security efforts. Currently we assess applications using the cloud security alliance's CAIQ framework and questionnaire. However while 90% of what gets assessed is cloud based, I think we need another set of questions for internal assets.

Question: Has anyone ever worked within an organization that utilizes multiple frameworks that would switch between the framework based on the type of data or technical specifications in order to complete a risk assessment?

Comment: You don't ask a question here...Could you edit and clarify what you're wondering about?

Comment: I apologize. Not sure how I managed to do that. I've edited the post.

Comment: I have worked with multiple frameworks, but still can't see what your question is...

Comment: Sorry Rory, The first time I posted, I think I was rushing. The Second time, I just didn't make myself clear. Hopefully I'm clear now. I just need to know if this is unique, because it is to me.

Comment: Still, the answer is yes. You either jump across to a different one, or you incorporate the various frameworks in your own overarching framework. It's exactly as it sounds. I'm still not really seeing a question...

Comment: I appreciate the response. That was really all I needed to know...